# Why will my Skylanders Giant Wii game not work in the Wii U?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u, skylanders-giants

My 6year old son loves playing Skylanders. He has the Skylanders Giant game for the Wii and is wanting to play it on his new Wii U. I thought the Wii games were supposed to still work on the Wii U, but for the Giants game it just says cannot read disc. It works in the regular Wii, so is it the disc or do these games just not work on the Wii U?

Any suggestions to what we can do or what is wrong? I'm not a big gamer, so I don't know how to help him.
Thanks,
gamer's mom

Comment: I'm pretty sure the WiiU doesn't feature backwards compatibility to Wii games, but I don't actually own one myself.

Comment: @gnomeslice the wii u [feature good backwards compatibility](http://www.nintendo.com/wiiu/built-in-software/wii-menu) actually.

Comment: Worst case scenario, buy only the Wii U version of the game (no portal or figures) and your son will use his current figures and portal. I'm unsure if the save games will be transferable.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I may have to buy just the Wii U disc because the Wii one is not working at all on the Wii U console. He just likes to play it over and over! Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the reason behind your problem, but I've found this article.

> The Wii U version of the game, which is also coming out on the 3DS,
>   PS3, Wii and Xbox 360 consoles, will have higher texture density and
>   screen resolution than its other console counterparts.
>
> *Skylanders: Giants* still has players using a *Portal of Power* to
>   transport plastic figures into the game as playable champions. Those
>   plastic figures, some of which no light up, save the champions
>   progress so they can be used on any platform, or account.
>
> While the Wii version of the Portal of Power **used a wireless USB
>   receive to communicate with the console**, the Wii U version **will use a
>   cord**.

Probably this is why the Wii version can't work on the Wii U, they use a different communication system.

So, yes, you may need to buy the Wii U version of the game.
But luckily the Wii version of the portal, as well as all figures, will still work with the Wii U version.

Source [here](http://www.polygon.com/gaming/2012/9/14/3332440/skylanders-giants-on-wii-u-will-have-richer-denser-graphics).

Comment: Thanks for the help, looks like that's what we'll have to do. Good to know the portal and figures will still work. :)